# "convert" curl rest api command to python

Tags: python

I have this curl command:

```
curl -X POST -s -k -u "admin:Password" -d '

{
"add_content": {
    "errata_ids": ["RHSA-2016:2124","RHBA-2016:2889"]
},
"content_view_version_environments": [{
    "content_view_version_id": 28
}]
}
' \

-H "Accept:application/json,version=2" \ -H "Content-Type:application/json" \ https://satellite.example.com/katello/api/content_view_versions/incremental_update
```

I need to convert it to python

this is what I have got so far:

```
def post_json(location, json_data):


result = requests.post(
    location,
    data=json_data,
    auth=(USERNAME, PASSWORD),
    verify=SSL_VERIFY,
    headers=POST_HEADERS)

return result.json()

json_data = {
    "add_content": {
        "errata_ids": ["RHSA-2016:2124","RHBA-2016:2889"]
    },
    "content_view_version_environments": [{
        "content_view_version_id": 301
    }]
}

push_errata = post_json(katello_api + "content_view_versions + "/incremental_update/" + "content_view_version_environments/" + "add_content['RHSA-2016:1912'])
```

I am getting `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

can you please help me to "convert" the curl command to python properly ?

Comment: Why there is '/' in `"/incremental_update/"` ?

Comment: Look how the syntax highlighting of the last line shows the problem. Not enough quotes, not enough plus signs. (This is why using [string formatting](https://pyformat.info/) us usually a better idea.)

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to run it in Python, one option is to use subprocess.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(['curl','-X', '''list your command here'''])
```